# Log Book / Diary

Tags: personal-information-management

I would like and application that can keep track of various events. It is not exactly a blog / dairy because the records would generally be short and need to include custom metadata. Here are some example of events to record:

- Taking medicine
- Exercises
- Doctor visits
- Food consumed
- Weight / Temperature / Blood pressure measurements
- Periods
- Sexual activity
- Meetings that happened
- Shops / Cafe / Restraints / Friends visited
- Many others

Those events would have:

- Something similar to tags to filter views
- Dates and optionally times
- Day / Week / Month Views
- Custom fields to export and probably make graphs from by an external tool

  - Field types could be text, multiple choice, duration, number, etc
  - Month view of, say weight, can produce a nice (exportable) table with numbers how weight has been changing
- Ability to share events tagged with certain tags with others
- Search / filter

The overall goal is to keep recorded timeline of certain things happening in one's life when memory cannot be relied on.

It does not have to be free, but preferably not subscription based. Self-hosted is a plus but not a requirement. In this day and age it would probably be a web app, may be with desktop / mobile clients.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at [Monica](https://github.com/monicahq/monica)

- You can self-host if you do not want the hosted solution.
- A [list of features can be found here](https://github.com/monicahq/monica#features).
- Many of the things mentioned in your requiremens can the tracked as tasks,activities, reminders, events, etc against a contact. You can add yourself as a contact...

Comment: Thank you for this, nice one. A few things such as not being able to customize date format, and also date rather time based reminders and events make it a bit less useful to me. Also was not able to select myself in settings to indicate that something is associated with me and not with another person. I feel a lot of potential, but it's not there yet. Thank you, once more!

Comment: Did you also add yourself as a contact? If so, you can associate stuff with you. I suggest you also ask questions related to this on the issues queue https://github.com/monicahq/monica/issues

Comment: e.g. Date format request https://github.com/monicahq/monica/issues/3335

Comment: Yeah, this issue is more than a year old, so I'm not holding my breath. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you are self-hosting, you can just change the format yourself in code. Anyway, let's know if you find any other system.